# How to write a macro that accepts a typename?

Tags: c++

The following code-

```
#define test_macro (some_typename) some_typename func (some_typename x) {return x;} 
test_macro (int)
```

does not compile with g++ 4.4.7 giving the following errors-

```
constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'some_typename'
unqualified-id before 'int'
')' before 'int'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using macros? Templates perhaps?

Comment: @EdHeal test_macro may be used by a C application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros have no idea about typenames or any other language features as they are a part of the preprocessor.  The only problem with your code is formatting, namely some extra spaces:

```
#define test_macro(some_typename) some_typename func (some_typename x) {return x;}
test_macro(int)
```

On a side note, when you need a typename to be a parameter, consider templates - they are good at it:)